# Calculate $\int_1^2\int_0^1\max(x,y)\,dx\,dy $

Tags: real-analysis

$\int_1^2\int_0^1\max(x,y)\,dx\,dy $ can I use the information that $y>x?$ According to wolfram alpha I may do it.  Would appreciate your help since I don't know why I may use the information. Does it something have to with the fact that I originally wrote it like $\int_A$ and $A$ is the space to integrate and in that space the information of $y$ is in there?

Comment: Then $\max(x,y)=y$.

Comment: In the region of integration we have $\max (x,y)=y$, then

$$\int_1^2\int_0^1\max(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy =\int_1^2\int_0^1y\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy$$

Comment: so i may use it and i have to take the whole region into account ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can but you should impose it inside the integral

**Hint**

$$\int_1^2\int_0^1\max(x,y)\,dx\,dy {=\int_1^2\int_0^1y\,dx\,dy \\=\int_1^2y\int_0^1\,dx\,dy}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you integrate $x$ between $0$ and $1$ and $y$ between $1$ and $2$. So $\max(x,y)=y$

Comment: so i  may use it ? the reason im asking is if you $\int_1^2 (1)dy \int_0^1max(x,y)dx$ it does not work out anymore and i simply made some changes

Comment: @MathsGuy: The $\max(x,y)$ cannot pull out of the $y$ integral, because it depends on $y$.

Comment: why ? According to Fubini i may do it.

Comment: $\int_0^1ydx=y\int_0^1 dx=y$

Comment: Then $\int_1^2 y dy=...$

Comment: No, Fubini allows you to interchange the order of integration. The $\max(x,y)$ pulls out of the inner, $x$ integral, but not the outer $y$ integral.

Comment: $\int_1^2 (1)dy \int_0^1max(x,y)dx$ whats wrong with that ?

Comment: The $\max(x,y)$ is no longer in the $y$ integral, that's what's wrong with it.

Comment: @MathsGuy It's not clear if the result of the integral over $x$ is multiplied with the result of the integral over $y$, or if the integration over $x$ is the used inside the integration over $y$. Your formula is confusing. Many might interpret it as $$\left(\int_1^2(1)dy\right)\left(\int_0^1\max(x,y) dx\right)$$

Comment: You can do $$\int_1^2\int_0^1\max(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_1^2y\,dy\cdot\int_0^1dx.$$

Comment: Mr Keister I know that i may do it. My question was why. How do i get to there?

Comment: Well, as has been noted by many: because $0\le x\le 1$ and $1 \le y\le 2,$ it follows that $x\le y$ everywhere on your region of integration. Therefore $\max(x,y)=y.$ It follows that $$\int_1^2\int_0^1\max(x,y)\,dx\,dy=\int_1^2\int_0^1y\,dx\,dy=\int_1^2y\int_0^1dx\,dy=\int_1^2y\,dy\cdot\int_0^1dx.$$